# What is the real meaning of if(!bool)?

Tags: c#, boolean, boolean-expression

I was wondering, what does exactly mean ! in the given expression :

```
bool myBool = AnyMethodThatReturnABoolean();
if(!myBool)
{
    // Do whatever you want
}
```

I now that I'm already using it when I expect myBool to be false, but is it more complex ?
**Does ! mean "== false" or "!= true"?**

Comment: it means "not" (¬) ..

Comment: ! when used with boolean is `not`

Comment: What would be the difference between `== false` and `!= true`?

Comment: Are you considering non-standard scenarios where a bool is returned that isn't internally 0 or 1 but some other number?

Comment: `if (myBool)` means `if (myBool == true)` and `if (!myBool)` means `if (myBool == false)`.

Comment: Consider reading the documentation or searching on Google for **at least** 5 minutes before asking us to do the search for you

Comment: first negate the value of myBool if the output of it is true, then execute the block

Comment: @Corak and harold, it can be usefull to know for a case where you use a nullable boolean (bool?).

Comment: @MatthieuFoltzer - agreed, but your example explicitly uses `bool`, not `bool?`.

Comment: @Corak I agree, but the answer would still be the same

Comment: @MatthieuFoltzer - no. With `bool?` it *does* make a difference to ask for `== false` or `!= true` (or `!value` for that matter) in the specific case of not having a value. `((bool?)null) == false` returns `false`. `((bool?)null) != true` returns `true` and `!((bool?)null)` returns `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [logical negation operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-negation-operator-).

> The ! operator computes logical negation of its operand. That is, it
>   produces true, if the operand evaluates to false, and false, if the
>   operand evaluates to true.

In your example

```
if(!myBool)
```

is like writing:

```
if(myBool == false)
```

Answer (score 2):

It simply inverts the value of the bool expression.

`True` becomes `False` and `False` becomes `True`.

`if` block will run only if expression inside the parentheses evaulates to `True`.

Answer (score 1):

it's the same as:

```
if(mybool == false){ 

      //some code
}
```

Just a shorthand way of writing it.